# Play Framework IF statement and FOR loop

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am new to MVC and following [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplates) I have a search page for resulting pdf metadatas by using Solr. My if statement and for loop in html side do not work

Searching.java in models folder:

```
public class Searching {

    public String q;

    public String outputTitle;
    public String outputAuthor;
    public String outputContent;
    public String outputPage;
    public String outputPath;

}
```

search function in Application.java:

```
    final static Form<Searching> searchForm = form(Searching.class);
    final static List<Searching> searchList = new ArrayList<Searching>(); 

public static Result search() {
Form<Searching> filledForm = searchForm.bindFromRequest();
        Searching searched = filledForm.get();

....(database connection lines)

QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    if(results.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("SEARCH NOT FOUND");
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {

            searched.outputTitle = (String)results.get(i).getFirstValue("title");
            searched.outputAuthor = (String)results.get(i).getFirstValue("author");
            searched.outputPage =results.get(i).getFirstValue("pageNumber").toString();
            searched.outputContent = (String)results.get(i).getFirstValue("content");
            searched.outputPath =  (String)results.get(i).getFirstValue("path");    
            searchList.add(searched);   
        }
        System.out.println("\nresults.getNumFound(): "+ searched.outputFound);
        System.out.println("results.size(): "+results.size());
        }
    return play.mvc.Results.ok(search.render(searched, searchForm, searchList)); 
    }
```

search.scala.html

```
@(searched: Searching, searchForm: Form[Searching], searchList: List[Searching])
.. some buttons,a search bar...
@if(searchList.isEmpty()) {
                <h1>Error</h1>
            } else {
                @for(search <- searchList) {
                <ul>Title: @search.outputTitle</ul> 
                <ul>Author: @search.outputAuthor <a href="@search.outputPath" download>Download PDF</a></ul>
                <ul>Number of Page(s): @search.outputPage</ul>
                }   
            }
```

Java code works well. I can see outputs on the terminal, but my html side has problem and it shows one book many times according to size of searchList

Comment: You should really give proper names to your variables and parameters. Anyway, the `listForm: List[Searching]` parameter that you use for iteration in the template is empty. Either fill the List with data or iterate over something else

Comment: What do you mean proper names? Then I think I need to change inside for loop in Application.java

Comment: Well naming your parameter `listForm` and then saying that it is of type `List[Searching]` is not really intuitive. The point is, you are just creating some static field and the passing it to the template - of course it will contain no data. There is also another problem in the Java code - you iterate over the `results` but use only one variable (`searched`) - this way you are always overwriting the data.

Comment: Edited question.I really do not know how I forgot to add variables in List. Now, I search "Microsoft" and the program finds two different books on terminal, but html page shows me only one book two times. I removed `static` from `final static List<Searching> searchList = new ArrayList<Searching>();` and got an error `non-static variable searchList cannot be referenced from a static context`. I also cannot do `searchList.add(results);`. It offers me to change add() as addAll(), then offers to change again addAll() to add() and so on. Is there a problem with my logic or something different?

Comment: The line `searchList.add(searched);` must be inside the for-loop. Right now you have a list but with just one element. You think you have two elements because you print `results.getNumFound()` but actually you should compare `results.getNumFound()` and `searchList.size()` and see that they differ. So, put the above mentioned line in the for-loop

Comment: Edited code. Put that line in the for-loop and issue still exists. Also `results.getNumFound()` and `searchList.size()` have the same value which is 2.
[link](http://postimg.org/image/l5vcx3moz/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107412/discussion-between-anton-and-ali19033).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am posting the answer explicitly even though I was able to help the OP in the chat - maybe somebody else is running into such problem but did not check the chat:*

The problem is even though you have the line in the for-loop you are still using the same `searched` variable. What you have to do is to reinitialize the variable when entering the loop. Something like:

```
for (...) {
    searched = new Searching();
    searched.outputTitle = (String)results.get(i).getFirstValue("title");
    ....
    searchList.add(searched);
}
```

This solves the problem with the duplicates and everything is fine now.